In Daniel 8-12, how can the Messiah and Michael both be our Prince?
Daniel 8:11

It became great, even as great as the Prince of the host. And the
regular burnt offering was taken away from him, and the place of his
sanctuary was overthrown.

Daniel 8:25

By his cunning he shall make deceit prosper under his hand, and in his
own mind he shall become great. Without warning he shall destroy many.
And he shall even rise up against the Prince of princes, and he shall
be broken—but by no human hand.

Daniel 9:25

Know therefore and understand that from the going out of the word to
restore and build Jerusalem to the coming of the Messiah, the Prince,
there shall be seven weeks. Then for sixty-two weeks it shall be built
again with squares and moat, but in a troubled time.

Daniel 10:13

The prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty-one days,
but Michael, foremost of the chief princes, came to help me, for I was left there with the kings of Persia,

Daniel 10:21

"But I will tell you what is inscribed in the book of truth: there is
none who contends by my side against these except Michael, your
Prince."

Daniel 12:1

“At that time shall arise Michael, the great Prince who has charge of
your people. And there shall be a time of trouble, such as never has
been since there was a nation till that time. But at that time your
people shall be delivered, everyone whose name shall be found written
in the book."

From these six key passages, we learn that the Messiah is the Prince, and that Michael is our Prince. How can this be, and does this imply that we have two princes, or that the Messiah is the incarnation of Michael?

Michael is "one of" the chief Princes, therefore there are more than one chief Prince.  He is the chief Prince who has charge over Daniel's people Israel.  10:13 is a different word than 9:25.  There are multiple chief Princes (sar) but there is only one Messiah the Prince (naw-gheed).

Michael is "your Prince". He is the foremost of the chief princes, the firstborn of all creation.

@MikeBorden, indeed there are many chief princes but there is only one Messiah

Michael is a Prince in relation to other angelic personages. On earth, there are Princes who rule over men. The Messiah is he who is come to reign in the kingdom of the heavens, another realm than either the world of men or the array of angelic principalities and powers. I would have thought this was very clear from both Old and New Testament scripture.

Note that this question is identical to In Daniel 8-12, how can the Messiah and Michael both be our Prince? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange

@RayButterworth – I'm shooting two darts and seeing which one sticks first.

The term "archangel" appears twice in the New Testament, both times in the singular and preceded by the definite article "the". The prefix "arch" means "chief" or "principal".

Thessalonians 4:16: "For the Lord himself will come down from heaven with a cry of command, with the voice of an archangel, and with the sound of the trumpet of God.    Michael the archangel is the lord Jesus.

@Kristopher, I 100% agree!

@Kristopher The verse you quoted says "the voice of an archangel" and not "the voice of the archangel" in most translations (including the one you offered).

@MikeBorden. Do you use that verse to prove that Jesus is one of many or at least several archangels?  How would Jesus have an archangels voice and not be the archangel?  Jesus the unique one of a kind(monogenes) son of God who alone was directly formed by God cannot be one of a group of Chief angels. He is the only archangel and would logically speak with the voice of an archangel.

@Kristopher The verse does not say that the archangel's voice is His voice, nor does it say that He is playing the trumpet.  His coming ocurrs with those things is all that is said.

@MikeBorden  are there 2 angelic armies in heaven?

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/98051/11555    To read more of Mike Borden’s reasoning on the voice of the archangel

Michael is a Prince in relation to other angelic personages. On earth, there are Princes who rule over men.
The Messiah is he who is come to reign in the kingdom of the heavens, another realm than either the world of men or the array of angelic principalities and powers.
Though it is also true that the Messiah is exalted, in resurrection and ascension, to the right hand of God, in a rearrangement of creation, thus a new creation, wherein he and his redeemed shall 'judge angels'.

Know ye not that we shall judge angels? [1 Corinthians 6:3 KJV]

I would have thought this was very clear from both Old and New Testament scripture.
One could spend a lot of time cataloguing all such instances but it is always far better to read scripture, daily and consecutively ; and also to study words in their proper context and in their development throughout scripture, rather than for me just to quote disparate texts in a brief 'answer' on the internet.

Further, in response to comment :
who is standing up for the sons of thy people, (see Young's Literal Daniel 12:1) is a spiritual reference to the redeemed of the Lord (redemption leads to sonship) that angels watch over (providentially) his people upon earth. See also Take heed that ye despise not one of these little ones; for I say unto you that in Heaven their angels do always behold the face of My Father who is in Heaven. Matthew 18:10 KJV

@OneGodOneLord who is standing up for the sons of thy people, (see Young's Literal Daniel 12:1) is a spiritual reference to the redeemed of the Lord (redemption leads to sonship) that angels watch over (providentially) his people upon earth. The connections you are making do not stand up to in-depth scrutiny. See also Take heed that ye despise not one of these little ones; for I say unto you that in Heaven their angels do always behold the face of My Father who is in Heaven. Matthew 18:10 KJV.

NigelJ – "Michael your Prince"? Michael shall arise, and all the saints will be delivered? How is he not the Son of God?

@OneGodOneLord Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil he disputed about the body of Moses, durst not bring against him a railing accusation, but said, The Lord rebuke thee. Jude 1:9 Michael is not 'The Lord'.

– But the Angel of the LORD says the exact same thing in Zechariah 3:2 to free the high priest Joshua!

@OneGodOneLord Which proves that the angel is Michael. And Michael is not the Lord. This is going in circles. I shall stop commenting now.

NigelJ – and with that admission, you are cornered! Because the Angel of the LORD carries the divine Name, he is worshipped by the patriarchs as he is God's Son. The Angel of the LORD (Michael) calls himself the God of Abraham because he is God's personal agent and mediator!

The name Michael means one who is like el.  Michael is an el.  Michael is one of the messiah's names.
Messiah's earthly names were Yahushua (Yahu saves), Emmanuel (El is with us), Israel (one who contends with El).
Michael and the Messiah are the same person.

Michael is a discription of the Messiah in heaven.
